# Rasterization of Poly3DCollection in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

When trying to enforce rasterization of a `Poly3DCollection` object in Matplotlib, I get the following error message (and I can confirm no rasterization is applied):

```
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib/artist.py:788: UserWarning: Rasterization of '<mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d.Poly3DCollection object at 0x2b49e8faeba8>' will be ignored
  warnings.warn("Rasterization of '%s' will be ignored" % self)
```

It is possible to rasterize the entire figure, but it is obviously preferable to only rasterize some objects, while keeping items like axes, labels, key, text, etc. as vector graphics.

I have tried using the following syntax in my code:

- `ax.add_collection3d(Poly3DCollection(polygons, rasterized=True), zs='z')`
- `c = Poly3DCollection(polygons)` and then `c.set_rasterized(True)`

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14032763/rasterizing-matplotlib-axis-contents-but-not-frame-labels), it is possible to rasterize a `PolyCollection` (without the 3D bit) object.

Any suggestions?

Here is an MWE:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d import Poly3DCollection, Line3DCollection

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

ax.set_xlim([0, 4])
ax.set_ylim([0, 4])
ax.set_zlim([0, 4])

polygons = [[(3, 1, 1), (1, 3, 1), (1, 1, 3)]]

ax.add_collection3d(Poly3DCollection(polygons, facecolors='r', rasterized=True), zs='z')

plt.show()
```

Comment: I don't know for sure but suspect that this is impossible by design. How would you handle, for example, a rotation of the viewing angle that is not a multiple of 90 degrees, if the 3d object being viewed has been rasterized (into cubes?)?

Comment: @Paul Rasterization is only meant for export. There is nothing rasterized on screen so you can still rotate your plot as usual.

Comment: Oh, I assumed that it would be handled as e.g. in gimp, where when you rasterize an object, it is actually converted to a bitmap, AFAIK. Thanks for the clarification, @ImportanceOfBeingErnest

Comment: @Paul You are completely right. The point is, rasterization in matplotlib will only affect the exported file. In the exported pdf you'll see the shape is bitmap-like (see screenshot in my answer below). Since you cannot rotate the plot once it is in pdf format, this is all perfectly fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First note that rasterization is only useful for exporting in a vector graphics, like pdf. I am assuming that this is what you are talking about here, so I suppose you would call something like `plt.savefig("some.pdf")` at the end.

I think someone just forgot to allow rasterizations for 3D objects.

A fix would be to go into the matplotlib source code, locate

```
python\lib\site-packages\mpl_toolkits\mplot3d\art3d.py
```

In the imports section add

```
from matplotlib.artist import allow_rasterization
```

and further down inside `Poly3DCollection` find its `draw` method (In my case it's at line 709) and add `@allow_rasterization`. It should then look like

```
@allow_rasterization
def draw(self, renderer):
    return Collection.draw(self, renderer)
```

If then running the above code, plus saving it to pdf, the triangle is rasterized. Screenshot of pdf:

[image]

Comment: Apparently, the bug is already known, and a pull request also exists on GitHub. https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/10158

Comment: Yes, I made that pull request in addition to answering the question. However, I will still need to add rasterization to all mpl3d methods.